# dplyr mutate converts double to logical, bug or correct?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

See the code below

```
library(dplyr)

df = tibble(
  x1 = c(0, 1, 2, 3),
  x2 = c(0, NA, 1, NA),
  x3 = as.double(NA)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(x1 = ifelse(x1 == 0, NA, x1)) %>% 
  mutate(x2 = ifelse(x2 == 0, NA, x2)) %>% 
  mutate(x3 = ifelse(x3 == 0, NA, x3)) %>% 
  str()

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(x1 = ifelse(x1 == 0, NA, x1)) %>% 
  mutate(x2 = ifelse(x2 == 0, NA, x2)) %>% 
  mutate(x3 = ifelse(x3 == 0, NA, x3)) %>% 
  str()
```

Column x3 is converted to logical which caused an issue in one of my codes recently.

Is this correct or is this a bug?

I cannot get the logic as for columns x1 and x2 this works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, `NA` is a length-1 *logical* vector.

```r
class(NA)
#> [1] "logical"
```

The equivalent missing value for numeric data is `NA_real_`. This is usually overlooked because when `NA_real_` is printed, it is printed as `NA`:

```r
NA_real_
#> [1] NA

class(NA_real_)
#> [1] "numeric"
```

When you create a numeric vector with `NA` values, the `NA` are actually converted to `NA_real_`:

```r
dput(c(1, NA)[2])
#> NA_real_
```

In your example, you have already explicitly converted `x3` to `double`, so the column is now filled with `NA_real`

```r
class(as.double(NA))
#> [1] "numeric"

dput(as.double(NA))
#> NA_real_
```

This is all as expected. But inside `ifelse`, the first argument is always *logical*. In your case, `x3` is the equivalent of:

```r
c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)
```

But the expression `c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real) == 0` returns a *logical* vector, since it is a logical test; you are asking "are these values equal to zero?".

```r
class(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_) == 0)
#> [1] "logical"
```

Inside `ifelse`, although there are parameters to specify what to return for `TRUE` and `FALSE` values of the logical test, there is no value for what to return in the event of `NA`, and a logical `NA` is returned if you attempt the comparison.

In the case of column `x2`, there is one numeric value returned by `ifelse`, so the other 3 logical `NA` values in that column are converted to `NA_real_`.

```r
x2 <- c(0, NA, 2, NA)
ifelse(x2 == 0, NA, x2)
#> [1] NA NA  2 NA

dput(ifelse(x2 == 0, NA, x2)[1])
#> NA_real_
```

However, in the final column, there are *only* logical `NA` values returned, and nothing in your code to convert them to `NA_real_`, so the column remains a logical `NA` column.

There are a few possible solutions, but the way to do this in `dplyr` is to use `if_else` instead of `ifelse`, since this does the same thing as `ifelse` but preserves type safety. You will also need to specify `NA_real_` to keep the type safety:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(x1 = if_else(x1 == 0, NA_real_, x1)) %>% 
  mutate(x2 = if_else(x2 == 0, NA_real_, x2)) %>% 
  mutate(x3 = if_else(x3 == 0, NA_real_, x3)) %>% 
  str()
#> tibble [4 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ x1: num [1:4] NA 1 2 3
#>  $ x2: num [1:4] NA NA 1 NA
#>  $ x3: num [1:4] NA NA NA NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: NA_real_ seems to be the solution! thanks for the detailed explanation